# Completed Bachelor of Engineering in Chemical need advise to take Master in Chemical Engineering

Tags: masters, engineering, bachelor

This is behalf of my sister posting here. she has completed her Bachelor of Engineering in Chemical and ready for Masters in Chemical. My question is whether any other available category under chemicals like bio or pure chemical, thermal etc. Which one is good in scope out of India.

She needs to take (Environmental engineering) in chemical, but my friends are advising not to take any core related chemical engineering because in India 90% of the company refused to take women employees to work in any chemical companies.

Doing Masters in Canada, Germany which one is good? How much cost per year? Which College/university will be good? How long the course duration? What are the basic requirement like IELTS etc need to consider before applying?

Regards,

Comment: What does she want to do? That seems the more important consideration.

Comment: She needs to take (Environmental engineering) in chemical, but my friends are advising not to take any core related chemical engineering because in India 90% of the company refused to take women employees to work in any chemical companies

Answer (score 1):

It seems very hard to continue in a field in which you have no real future. I can't offer alternative fields, not being well versed in any sort of engineering, but I can offer two thoughts.

Some people are willing to study something purely for the love of it and not for employment. That may well be impossible in your sister's case. But if employment isn't necessary then it might be an option to just continue. But only if the true love of the field is there.

The second idea is that if she becomes the very best person in the field - first in class - and can offer more than any other candidate then those normally discriminatory companies may take notice. But this is a hard path. In fact, many successful women outshine the males at the same "level" of employment. Still sadly a fact.

As a bonus idea. If she truly loves the field, then academia might offer a career path with somewhat lower levels of discrimination. One hopes anyway. But again, this is a longer path with its own difficulties.

Good luck to her.

Your recent edit suggests study outside India. That might be possible provided that she is willing and able to immigrate to some other country permanently. But in a difficult situation, the costs might mean less than the opportunity.

Comment: If chemical engineering is a regulated industry in India, a career in government might be an option.